# aws cdk deploy failure from rate exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

While doing a `cdk deploy` of a large `Stack`, that underwent many changes since the previous deployment, the following `CREATE_FAILED` occurred:

> CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy ... Unable to retrieve capacity for resource: ... scalable dimension: lambda:function:ProvisionedConcurrency. Reason: Rate exceeded

Note the "..." were used to obfuscate stack specific names.

**How can this rate be increased, or cdk be throttled, to allow a successful deployment?**

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: I would suggest to open a support request with AWS. I doubt this is CDK related, looks more like a pure CFN issue since that is what is actually sending the requests. And CFN should have proper retry and backoff strategies in place to avoid / remedy "rate exceeded" exceptions. How many relevant resources do you have in your stack? Do they have any dependencies on each other?